# Returning the Object from a Pointer in a function such as a Linked List

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I'm a bit confused when it comes to Pointers and References in c++.

I understand that only Pointers can be null. So for my custom linked list class, I have:

```
ObjectNode* head;   // Pointer to the first item of the list
ObjectNode* last;   // Pointer to the last item of the list
```

Similarly, in my ObjectNode class, I have

```
SimObject object;   // The actual Object (cannot be null)
ObjectNode* next;   // Pointer to next Node
ObjectNode* prev;   // Pointer to previous Node
```

That way, my next and prev variables can be null, using

```
next = null;
```

However, my get methods are:

```
ObjectNode ObjectList::getHead() {
    return head;
}

ObjectNode ObjectList::getLast() {
    return last;
}
```

which gives the conversion error that would occur. So I'm probably misunderstanding something vital, and I'm not sure how I'm meant to return that Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be returning an ObjectNode*

Remember, it's SimObject which cannot be null, ObjectNode* can in fact be null, and in that case there's no actual node in existence. A null return value from GetHead means the list is empty.

When you use GetHead, the code that calls that needs to check if the returned value is null however.

If you want to get the *object* pointed to by head, then you have to either make a function for that or take the pointer that's returned, check if it's not null, then get the object:

```
ObjectNode *head = list.GetHead();
if(head != null)
{
    SimObject s = head->object;
}
```

However, you need to carefully consider how other code is going to be accessing the list, what an empty list means and how brittle it is if the calling-code doesn't do the right thing (e.g. if the calling code doesn't check whether GetHead returns null or not). Look at how std::list works, then replicate that functionality in your own list (only the bits you need). Then you have the best-case scenario that you can drop in your list or std::list interchangeably.

e.g. instead of "GetHead()" use "begin()", then set "end()" to return null, and overload the ++ operator for ObjectNode* to make it ObjectNode::next. Then you can loop over your custom list with:

```
for(auto i = mylist.begin();  i != mylist.end(); i++)
{
}
```

The same as std::list

Comment: Ah right I see
I hadn't even considered that having to check outside  the class for a null value would be sub-optimal
Thanks for explaining it clearly to me